# PySide QLabel doesn't fill the available height

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

In the GUI, the styling applied to the QLabel is applied only upto the height of the text in it. How do I increase it to fill the available region?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label = QtGui.QLabel('5')
        label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = label.palette()
        p.setColor(label.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.red)
        label.setPalette(p)
        layout.addWidget(label)

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: QLabel Example]

Comment: So is `label.setAutoFillBackground(True)` the line used to indicate that the label should be of same size as parent?

Comment: No this line is used to let you change the background color of the label. If you remove this line the color will not change. I think the widgets take as much space as they can by default.